# COMPARING Visual Basic sql to Java sql

Tags: java, sql, winforms, sql-server-2005, sqlclient

This is my way of connecting my project on Visual Basic (winform application) and trigger the `SELECT STATEMENT` to the SQLSERVER, my problem now is that I dunno if this is the same way to connect my project on JAVA application. (of course I know that it should be `Imports java.sql.*` instead of Imports `System.Data.SqlClient`)

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Try
            Dim querystring As String = "SELECT MAX(pIDNo) FROM dbo.Patients"
   Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****")
                Dim command As New SqlCommand(querystring, connection)
                connection.Open()
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
                Dim value = String.Empty
                While reader.Read
                    value = reader.GetString(0)
                End While
                txtPNumber.Text = Today.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2) & Today.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & (Integer.Parse(value.Substring(4, value.Length - 4)) + 1).ToString("D4")
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            txtPNumber.Text = Today.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2) & Today.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & num.ToString("D4")
        End Try
```

It's kinda hard to understand on how to connect my java application to SQLSERVER because I'm lack of information regards with suchs things. could anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Please check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html

Comment: @Sudhanshu - am I gonna do all of this before connecting my project in SQL SERVER? [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html)

Comment: I guess you still need to know the way of connecting to the database in Java - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Comment: There's a time that I run the program and then a error showed up, it says : "unable to connect the user=****" how to avoid that? can you give a a link that shows simple connection that does not required any login before accessing the DATABASE on SQLSERVER?

Comment: there's a 2 option on the link that you gave me , MySQL and Java DB what am I gonna use since my DATABASE is from SQLSERVER?

Comment: Just don't set user and password, provided your database doesn't require them.

Comment: but how if my DATABASE already have a username and password, what should I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to SQL Server from Java using Microsoft JDBC Driver for Java: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx

You can view some sample applications that use Microsoft JDBC Driver for Java here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342346%28v=sql.110%29.aspx